# Is this a valid proof for why all modules over a field are projective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, modules, projective-module

Let $F$ a field and $V$ an $F$-module (i.e. an $F$-vector space). Then $V$ has a basis, and so $V$ is free. All free modules are projective, so $V$ is projective too.

Is this ok?

Comment: Yes, it is OK. The main point of course is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32429/free-module-implies-projective-module).

Comment: "ok proof" = "proof"...

Comment: @JeanMarie I of course meant "ok" as in "valid"

Comment: As a generalization, all modules over a division ring are also projective.

Comment: Having all modules projective characterizes semisjmple rings. Having all modules free characterizes division rings.